# Having Issues on Using PHP glob() in WordPress

Tags: php

Using pure PHP code inside WordPress I am having trouble on getting the `glob()` work to generate image source.

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" style="height=600px; width=1000px;">
    <?php
     $directory = "http://geocaa.com/wp-content/themes/Booting/img/services/";
     $images = glob($directory . "*.png");
      foreach($images as $image)
       {
        echo '<div class="dynamic item">';
        echo ' <img src="'.$image.'" alt="...">';
        echo ' </div>';
       }
    ?>
</div>
```

As you can see I tried to hardcoded the `$directory` as `"http://geocaa.com/wp-content/themes/Booting/img/services/";` and also I already investigate on these two Post [[Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295175/wordpress-php-glob-not-working) & [Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42030975/wordpress-using-glob-returns-an-empty-array) ] regarding the same issues but the solutions there still not working for me!

The `get_theme_root()` retuns nothing but the `get_template_directory()` is returning something which is more like

```
$images = glob(get_template_directory().$directory . "*.png");
```

> /home/vcbb/public_html/wp-content/themes/geocaa/img/services/img.png

and useless for image src

I also tried `get_template_directory_uri()` but still getting empty array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use *paths* with `glob`, not *URLs*.

But `src` attributes needs URLs.

So something like this should work:

```
$base_dir = trailingslashit(get_template_directory());
$dir      = 'img/services/';
$images   = glob($base_dir.$dir.'*.png');

foreach($images as $image) {
    $url = get_theme_file_uri($dir.basename($image));
    printf('<div class="dynamic item"><img src="%s" alt=""></div>', esc_url($url));
}
```

Where I make use of:

- [`get_template_directory`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory/) To obtain the root path of (parent) theme
- [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) to obtain just the *file name* of the current image file path
- [`get_theme_file_uri`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_theme_file_uri/) to obtain the full URL of the image, in a child-theme friendly way: if the image is found in child theme it will be used from there, otherwise will be used from parent theme.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to try `get_stylesheet_directory()`.

```
$images = glob(get_stylesheet_directory()."/img/services/*.png");
```

You're using `glob` on an URL, not a path actually.

Comment: Can you try to dump this : `var_dump(get_stylesheet_directory()."/img/services/");`

Comment: Are you trying to get the images from another website with your glob ?

Comment: No they are in theme image folder

Comment: Ok, so you're sure that this path contain your images ? And that `/home/vcbb/public_html/wp-content/themes/VanBeautyBoot/img/‌​services/` exist ?